# WCF 4.0 Service crashes

Tags: wcf

I have wcf service hosted in iis 7.0.
It was working well for the past year, but now suddenly it's crashing and restarting every few minutes.
I looked at the trace file, and I see the error but I don't know what it means. I tried googling it but no luck. I checked the settings in IIS. It looks ok.

This is how my trace looks like. If someone can help me understand this trace, it will be good.

[image]

Comment: The error says you have a null parameter somewhere.  Look at the stack trace to see if it tells you what line it occurred on.

Comment: Even if I have a null reference exception, why all the service is crashing and restarting?

Answer (score 1):

This are pure assumptions, but as far I guess by looking at your traces and what you wrote:

- You are using a **net.pipe** WCF host
- The endpoint address of your host is `net.pipe://tstwebashitv...` something, so you are not using a the `net.pipe://localhost/...` format (assuming tstwebashitv is not a server name, and your net.pipe is not remote)
- The service used to work for a long time

So I assume there is a possibility that another named pipe WCF host is running on the same machine, and might cause conflict.

That's why I suggest to check those points:

- Have net.pipe endpoints adresses under this format: `net.pipe://localhost/something` instead of `net.pipe://something`.
- Check [HostNameComparisonMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.hostnamecomparisonmode(v=vs.110).aspx) setting in the `NetNamePipeBinding` section : it is better to set it to `Exact` to ensure running hosts receives messages addressed to them.

Basically, if the `HostNameComparisonMode` is not set, then the `StrongWildcard` default mode is used and the host name in the net.pipe address is discarded.

If you have a net pipe address set as 'net.pipe://something', then "something" is considered as a server name and is discarded. So several host running that way could conflict together.